# Embed widget [to, into, onto, on] your website

Tags: prepositions

You can take a piece of Google Map and embed it into your own website or blog. What is the correct usage of the word embed as a verb?

Comment: As a web developer in North America I would usually say "into" if referring to the website or the source code, as in "embed it into your webpage."  If someone said "embed that **on** the website" it would make perfect sense as well.  With a blog, I would probably say "embed it into your blog page," or maybe just "embed it on your blog."  But that's a more casual, less technical usage.  The answer by JonMark Perry is a very good explanation.

Comment: "Embed" means to surround, enclose, or incorporate, so "on", or "onto" wouldn't be good words.  "To" would not make sense.  "Into" or "in" would be appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

A website can be seen as a [container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_(abstract_data_type)) for a variety of HTML objects, of which the [<embed>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#embed) tag is one.

Most references in this sense place objects **into** a container, quoting Wikipedia for example:

> - create an empty container;
> - insert objects into the container;
> - delete objects from the container;
> - delete all the objects in the container;
> - access the objects in the container;
> - access the number of objects in the container.